# How can I use linq to sql with sql server sparse columns?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a table with more than 1200 columns and it uses sparse columns feature of sql server 2008 R2.

When I try to use linq to sql based on classes automatically generated in Visual Studio 2010 (O/R designer), I can't set individual columns. Sample code as follows:

```
    var sparse = new SparseColsTestDataContext();
    var input = new mydata();
    input.status_is_ready = true;
    sparse.mydatas.InsertOnSubmit(input);
    sparse.SubmitChanges();
```

leads to this exception:

```
The target column list of an INSERT, UPDATE, or MERGE statement cannot contain both a sparse column and the column set that contains the sparse column. Rewrite the statement to include either the sparse column or the column set, but not both.
```

The exception is self explanatory: linq appears to be inserting using both the individual status_is_ready column and the column set that contains it.

The sparse column: `SpecialPurposeColumns` is exposed as an XElement by the `mydata` class, which is another problem. If I want to use that field instead of `status_is_ready` then I need to create an XML content such as

```
<field1>value1</field1><field2>value2<field2>
```

as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521(v=SQL.100).aspx) But I could not do that either because I can only set value of one column with an XElement instance that matches the column name. In other words, it is impossible to construct the xml fragment above with XElement.

Hence the question: how am I supposed to use use linq to sql with sparse columns?

By the way, I could not find a single tutorial or document that shows how to use linq to sql (or entity framework) with sparse columns. So any urls/links would help as well.